# Маппинг для классов в определении которых есть список

Tags: c#, automapper

Есть два класса:

```
 Class A {
 public string someField {get; set;}
 public List<SomeOneClass> listClassA  {get; set;}

}

Class B {
 public string someField {get; set;}
 public List<SomeOtherClass> listClassB  {get; set;}

}
```

Есть объект типа A

```
A source = new A();
```

Пробую задать маппинг с помощью Automapper-а д них классов A и B так:

```
 Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<A, B>()
 .ForMember(des => des.listClassA, src => src.MapFrom( s => s.listClassB)));
```

но маппинг для листов так не работает. Господа, в чём ошибка?

Comment: [Читали](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays)?

Comment: Не за что. Можете запостить как ответ, а потом принять его.

Comment: У меня почему-то нет возможности отметить Ваш комментарий как ответ. Могу только проголосовать за него, как за полезный

Comment: Я имею в виду, что вы свой комментарий с кодом можете разместить как ответ :).

Answer (score 1):

andreycha, спасибо Вам большое. Данную статью читал, но видно, не внимательно.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Src, OMAltRight>()); 
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>(); 
var res = Mapper.Map<List<A>, List<B>>(source.documents); 
B desc = Mapper.Map<A, B>(source); 
B.listClassB = res;
```